# React is firing onchange event multiple times ie 11

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I have markup:

```
<input type='file' onchange ={(e) => { this._onBrowse(e);}}/>
```

with definition of  `_onBrowse` as :

```
private _onBrowse(event): void{     
   event.target.value =null;
   event.stopPropogation();
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

On IE 11 default settings this:

```
event.target.value = null;
```

causes to fire change event three times.

Comment: Isn't setting the value to `null` considered a change to the `<input>`, which would fire off `onChange` again?

Comment: Doesn't happens in chrome/edge/firefox

Comment: If you make it a controller component you don't need to add any event listeners. :

`<input type='file' value={null} />`

Comment: correct the typo `stopPropgation()` to `stopPropagation()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not do this `event.target.value =null;` 
You are manipulating the DOM directly.

I suggest you make it a controlled component. 
You can read how to do it here
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: Still I am not sure why it works fine in other browsers